# Proper sentence structure

Tags: grammar

When using *if I were* and *if I was*--is there a rule of thumb one can rely on? I seem to remember it has something to do with fact and fantasy.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about a situation that may have **actually happened in the past**, use *if I was*. This is a regular past simple.

If you are talking about a **situation in the present that you assume is not true**, use *if I were*, the past subjunctive. Informally, some people also use *was* in this situation, but pedants like me will prefer *were*.

Note that this only applies to the situation in the *if* clause:  in the rest of the sentence, other points in time may be described.

> If the killer **was** inside the house before she came in, she would have noticed the forced door and fled.

We are talking about a situation in the past that may have been true: the killer may have been inside the house.

> If the killer **is** French, he must have fled the country by now.

A situation in the present that may be true.

> If the killer **were** French, he would have fled the country by now; but he hasn't, so he can't be French.

A hypothetical situation in the present: the killer cannot be French.

> If the killer **had been** French, he would have fled the country by then; but he didn't, so he can't have been French.

A hypothetical situation in the past: the killer can't have been French. The past perfect subjunctive.